# Tool to "un-define" a symbol in a relocatable ELF symbol table

Tags: gcc, llvm, ld, elf, binutils

Is there any utility to patch arbitrary symbols in ELF symbol table so that defined symbol becomes undefined? For example here is `readelf --syms` for a file that I'm going to process

```
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 8 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     ...
     5: 0000000000000000    13 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT    3 my_message
     6: 0000000000000000    19 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    5 print_msg
     7: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND puts
```

And here is expected output for the same binary where `my_message` has been un-defined:

```
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 8 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     ...
     5: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND my_message
     6: 0000000000000000    19 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    5 print_msg
     7: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND puts
```

An ELF file itself is relocatable. Modification should alter only symbol table. Actual section that contains original symbol definition should remain unchanged.
I've checked GNU Binutils and `objcopy` might be what I'm looking for but so far I haven't figured out any option (or combination) that would give me above described behavior.

In fact such tool should be straightforward enough to implement (even with no extra libraries like BFD), but I'm wondering if there is some existing thing that I might miss.

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish by undefining the symbol? Internal calls may not be redirected as a result.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer I plan to enforce linker to ignore some definitions in one object file so they will be resolved from other places. As you said this may not work for non-`GLOBAL` symbols due compiler may emit such relocations that later can not be converted by linker to jump slots or GOT entries (thus redirection to external DSOs is not possible). But on the other hand gABI defines `GLOBAL` symbols as preemptible, which means that they eventually are referenced via dedicated jump slot or GOT entry. So it should be possible to "undefine" them and get another definition from other dynamic library.

Comment: The compiler may have created local aliases, and the link editor will then resolve the locally. This happens with LTO, and also with `-fno-semantic-interposition`.

Comment: Right, `*.localalias.0` are all `LOCAL` so an approach that I mentioned won't work here. Anyway it is a user-controlled behavior if local aliases may be created or not. So this should be manageable for my project. Also it looks like only GCC supports `-fno-semantic-interposition` and my target compiler is Clang, it knows nothing about it.

Comment: Btw `-fno-semantic-interposition` looks somewhat redundant because `STV_PROTECTED` offers exactly the same semantics in a toolchain-agnostic way. Moreover, IMO, `-fno-semantic-interposition` violates gABI because it hardwires `GLOBAL` exports inside binary without letting user to preempt it and ,more important, unlike `STV_PROTECTED` it gives no way to guess about this by examining stripped loadable binary.

Comment: Not sure about the gABI violation—but symbol interposition is definitely an ODR violation if we're playing the standards game. Without LTO with a linker plugin, the compiler cannot know anything about `STV_PROTECTED`. It's also possible to do this manually, and some libraries do (see `libc_hidden_proto` and `libc_hidden_def` in glibc for an example).

Answer (score 1):

You may look at the 'anonymizer' example of [ELFIO](https://github.com/serge1/ELFIO/) library. The example overrides a symbol's name. Overriding of symbol's type can be implemented similarly. But processing of '.symtab' section will be required.

Not exactly the tool, but, a library that permits to implement such tool.